# reading logs from a different user

Tags: ubuntu, logging, users

Running Ubuntu at the moment - I have created a user to run a node.js app - however, that app is giving errors and logging it inside /var/log. I can't tail the logs because I'm logged in with a different user. any help on getting around this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the log file you want to read? What does `ls -l` give on that file?

Comment: you could have your admin add you to the group that owns the file and grant read rights on the file to the group. if the owner group is root, then they would probably have to change that to another group.

Comment: The other user is running a node.js app within his own home folder.  I went ahead and had the root user add me to that person's group to see if I can view his logs... 

`ls -l` shows `john:john` - I added myself to group `john`

Comment: does `ls -al` show that the group john has read access to the file? if so, can you now read the file?

Comment: Yep! added myself to group `john` worked!!! Thanks